# Title value was duplicated after a search

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table with data, and I have two inputs (start date and end date) to filter the records.

I can show you a little visual in image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZL4S.png)

I enter for example the date `06/02/2019` to `06/02/2020`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNb9c.png)

I press search

(...)

In fact, the title value has been duplicated?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwveX.png)

I have two methods:

- getPrices() which displays the data in the HTML table
- getDetails() which displays the title

HTML.component

```
<div class="container">
<div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom pb-3">
   <h2> Course history {{infoTitle}}</h2>
   <button type="button" (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary m-1 btnColor">Back</button>
</div>
<div class="pt-3 container">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<form #formulaire="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="formulaire.form.valid && getPrices()">
<div class="row mb-4 align-items-end">
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-2">
         <h5>Start date </h5>
         <input id="previous" name="previous" type="text" class="form-control form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="model.previous" bsDatepicker #previousModel="ngModel" required [maxDate]="(model.today)" (ngModelChange)="model.verifyToday()">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-2">
         <h5>End date   </h5>
         <input id="today" name="today" type="text" class="form-control form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="model.today" bsDatepicker #todayModel="ngModel" [minDate]="(model.previous)">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-2">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="formulaire.form.invalid">
         Search 
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

typeScript.component

```
export class HistoricalPricesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  infoTitle: string = "";
  lines: HistoryPoint[] = [];

  model: Currency = new Currency();
  svm: string;

  constructor(
    private location: Location,
    private service: HistoricalPricesService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let svm: string | null;
    svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('svm');
    if (!svm) {
      this.goBack();
      return;
    } 
    this.svm = svm;
    this.getPrices();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  getPrices(): void {
    this.service.getInstrumentHistoryEquities(this.svm,this.model).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.HISTO.POINT.length > 0) {
          this.lines = res.HISTO.POINT.reverse();
        }
        this.getDetails(this.svm);
    });
  }

  private getDetails(svm: string): void {
    this.service.getInstrumentInfo(svm).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
        this.infoTitle += " " + res.ADVTITRE.BASIQUETITRE.LABEL + " (" + res.ADVTITRE.BASIQUETITRE.PLACELABEL + ")";
    });
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

Comment: You are adding to the title each time you call `getDetails`, try setting the title instead.

Comment: How can I solve the problem please?

Comment: Use `=` instead of `+=`.